# why NotFound error occur in REST services with windows Phone app?

Tags: web-services, rest, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, http-status-code-404

i tried to connect REST web servie from windows phone 8 application.

it was working proberly for weeks but after no change in it I get this generic error :

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error:
>   NotFound.

i tried to test it by online  REST Clients and services works properly

i tried to handle Exception and parse it as webException by this code :

```
    var we = ex.InnerException as WebException;
    if (we != null)
    {
        var resp = we.Response as HttpWebResponse;
        response.StatusCode = resp.StatusCode;
```

and i get no more information and final response code is : "NotFound"

any one have any idea about what may cause this error?

there is already a trusted Certificate implemented on the server . the one who has the server suggested to have a DNS entry for the server, this entry should be at the customer DNS or in the phone hosts file .that what i done and worked for awhile but now it doesn't work however i checked that there is no thing changed

this is sample for Get Request it works proberly on Windwos Store apps :

```
async Task<object> GetHttps(string uri, string parRequest, Type returnType, params string[] parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                string strRequest = ConstructRequest(parRequest, parameters);
                string encodedRequest = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strRequest);

                string requestURL = BackEndURL + uri + encodedRequest;

                HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(requestURL, UriKind.Absolute)) as HttpWebRequest;

                request.Headers["applicationName"] = AppName;
                request.Headers["applicationPassword"] = AppPassword;
                if (AppVersion > 1)
                    request.Headers["applicationVersion"] = AppVersion.ToString();
                request.Method = "GET";

                request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

                var factory = new TaskFactory();
                var getResponseTask = factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);
                HttpWebResponse response = await getResponseTask as HttpWebResponse;
              //  string s = response.GetResponseStream().ToString();
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(returnType);
                    object obj = serializer.Deserialize(response.GetResponseStream());
                    return obj;
                }
                else
                {
                    var Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(returnType);
                    (Instance as ResponseBase).NetworkError = true;
                    (Instance as ResponseBase).StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
                    return Instance;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return HandleException(ex, returnType);
            }
        }
```

i tried to monitor connections from Emulator and i found this error in connection :

**

> Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the
>   transport stream.

**

Comment: Make sure that, internet is available or your web service is running the Windows Phone 8 Emulator's IE?

Comment: i am sure from that the service running & internet is available

Comment: Is your service runs on HTTPS protocol?

Comment: I think yes .. service is uploaded at client Servers it was woking proberly for all mobile platform but suddenly it stops working from Windows phone 8 apps Only

Comment: If the HTTPS protocol then you have to install security certificate, in wp there is no way to avoid the https certificate.

Comment: Install it on the server side?

Comment: Can you navigate to a server page through the integrated browser so you can manually accept and install the servers certificate?

Comment: there is already a trusted Certificate  implemented on the server . the customer which has the server and he suggested to have a DNS entry for the server, this entry should be at the customer DNS or in the phone hosts file .. that what i done and worked for awhile but now it doesn't work however i checked that there is no thing changed

Comment: Please show us how you are calling the service?

Comment: @atomaras    yes i can navigate to server

Comment: @Pranav this is sample for my get request :

Comment: Are you sure nothing change on both client & server, change in order of parameters or http verb (get or post) can sometimes causes same error

Comment: as my side nothing changed , as other side i am not sure but they said that there is no changes . when i test services through windows store app it works proberly. how can i find if there is any problem in server side ?

Answer (score 1):

You saw the client implement a server side certificate in the service. Did you have that certificate installed on the phone? That can be the cause of the NotFound error. Please, can you try to navigate to the service in the phone or emulator internet explorer prior to testing the app? If you do that, you can see the service working in the emulator/phone internet explorer? Maybe at that point internet explorer ask you about installing the certificate and then you can open your app, and it works.

Also remember if you are testing this in the emulator, every time you close it, the state is lost so you need to repeat the operation of installing the certificate again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried to connect host server through emulator and it already connects this server , tried to call server and entered authorization data but with no response and no certification install request

Comment: You're not going to see a dialog popup to install the certificate.  You would need to implement such a feature or manually install the certificate before running your app

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use SSL in production in general public application (not company-distribution app), you need to ensure your certificate has one of the following root authorities:
[SSL root certificates for Windows Phone OS 7.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521150%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

When we had same issue, we purchased SSL certificate from one of those providers and after installing it on server we were able to make HTTPS requests to our services with no problem.

If you have company-distribution app, you can use any certificate from company's Root CA.